# How to handle 'Bad file descriptor' error in read function of socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to write a simple socket program in c++. Once I run the following server program, it executes up to **acceptConnection()** function and after running the client it continues as expected. But finally, it ends with a Bad file descriptor error in **readSocket()** function. How can I fix this error or is there anything I am doing wrong? Thank you for your valuable time!

Server program

```
void Server2::createSocket(){
    #ifdef WIN32
    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed: " << iResult << std::endl;

    }
    #endif

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Create socket failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

void Server2::clearAdrressStructure(){

    bzero((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

}

void Server2::bindSocket(){
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Bind failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

void Server2::listenConnection(){

    int a = listen(sockfd, 5);

    if(a < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Listen failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

void Server2::acceptConnection(){
    clilen = sizeof(clien_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clien_addr, &clilen);

    if(newsockfd < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Accept failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "Server got connection from " << inet_ntoa(clien_addr.sin_addr) << " port " << ntohs(clien_addr.sin_port) << endl;
}

void Server2::sendMessage(){

    if(send(newsockfd, "Hello, World!\n", 13, 0) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Send failed with error " << err << endl;
        perror("Sending failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    bzero(buffer, 256);

}

void Server2::readSocket(){

    if(read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Read failed with error " << err << endl;
        perror("Reading failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "MESSAGE: " << buffer << endl;
}
```

Main method(if necessary)

```
int main(){

    Server2 server;

    server.createSocket();
    server.clearAdrressStructure();
    server.bindSocket();
    server.listenConnection();
    server.acceptConnection();
    server.sendMessage();
    server.readSocket();

    close(server.newsockfd);
    close(server.sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is logically impossible for anyone to help you because the shown code fails the requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help]. See [ask] for more help.

Comment: oh! I am sorry but I don't understand how to achieve the requirements for minimal reproducible example because this is the whole server program. There is nothing else to show and I found this code from the internet. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Which part of the instructions for producing a [mre] you are unclear about?

Comment: I added the Server class to show what I have implemented and how. Then the main method to show the order of the methods have been called. The error which says 'Bad file descriptor' occurs withing the "readSocket()" function.

Comment: I didn't ask what you did. I asked which part of a [mre] you are unsure about. Can you answer the following question: can someone cut/paste what you've shown, above, then attempt to compile, run, and reproduce your error? Unless you can answer "yes", how can you claim that what you showed meets the "reproducible" part of a [mre]? Of course, the answer is "no".